# Insert new column with increment value

Tags: awk, sed

I have file something like,

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

I need to insert new column at the beginning of file with increment value like:

```
1 1 2
4 3 4
7 5 6
10 7 8
```

How can I achieve that? I am using `awk -F' ' '{$1=++i FS $1;}1' OFS=' ' file` but I am not sure how to add incremental value and with evenly spaced.

Comment: What do you mean by indentation?

Comment: @madphysicist Evenly spaced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=" "; col1=1}{print col1,$1,$2; col1+=3}' file
```

Here we just make a variable called `col1` and initially set it `1`. Then after we print each record we increment it by `3`: `col1+=3`.